# Verifying a reference property in moq (NUnit)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.0, nunit, moq

I started with using moq for unit tests. 
All I wanna do is this: test "Execute" method of class A. the method accepts an IA type object and sets a simple property in it.

```
[TestFixture]
public class A
{
    public void Execute(object s)
    {
        if (s is IA)
        {
            (s as IA).ASimpleStringProperty = "MocktestValue";
        }
    }
}

public interface IA
{
    string ASimpleStringProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I wrote my unit test like this:

but this does not work with my test method below: Any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var person = new Mock<IA>();
    var a = new A();
    a.Execute(person.Object);
    person.VerifySet(ASimpleStringProperty = "MockytestValue", "FailedTest");
}
```

(I want to check if the ASimpleStringProperty is "Mocktestvalue" but couldn't for some reasons. Also, When I put
the debugging, i see ASimpleStringProperty is null!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo in value which you assigning to property - `MockytestValue` instead of `MocktestValue`. Also use `VerifySet` to check if property was set:

```
person.VerifySet(ia => ia.ASimpleStringProperty = "MocktestValue", "FailedTest");
```

BTW why your `A` class marked as `TestFixture`?

Comment: I still get a mock exception: FailedTest
Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: ia => ia.ASimpleStringProperty = "MocktestValue"
No setups configured.

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. are you using `VerifySet`?

Comment: According to the TestFixture attribute: It denotes that a class contains test method!

Comment: Yes, I have to verify that the Executemethod sets the "ASimpleSTringProperty" to "MockTestValue".. But, can you guide me where am I going wrong?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed. check what value exactly you are setting to property - maybe there is another typo. Also your VerifySet call is strange. Don't think it will be compiled. Use lambda

Comment: Thanks lazyberezovsky. There was a problem in typo. But, the problem is solved. Whenever the value is "MocktestValue" everything is fine. But, when i try debugging on a mock object, I get the value as null (On debugging mode)